# ASCII Values For Keyboard Key Press Events?

Tags: c#, hex, keyboard-events

I borrowed someones code that sends a key event to another process (hWnd). Here is the definition of that function:

```
public static void SendKey(ushort key, IntPtr hWnd)
{
    SetActiveWindow(hWnd);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0);
}
```

Where SendMessage is taken from a DllImport:

```
//sends a windows message to the specified window
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, int lParam);
```

As you can see, the SendKey method takes a **ushort** value for the key to be sent.

Does anyone know where I can find these values? I.e. if the user pressed the "7" key and I wanted to forward it how to i go from the 7 key event/callback to a ushort value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending ascii characters you can use type casting, here is the example:

```
System.Convert.ToUInt16('7')
```

For sending non ascii characters use virtual key codes. Reference can be found at 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Keys-Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx)...